# You do not have permissions to make this API call using SOAP for DoDirectPaymentReq

Tags: soap, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm going a little batty with this one. I remember having a ridiculous time the last time I tried to get this to work, and then they changed it!  I tried to import my old user but it says the password isn't right.

Below is the soap I'm posting to https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/2.0/ This all worked before, and it still is working in the production environment, but whenever I try to run this in the sandbox I get

LONGMESSAGE=You do not have permissions to make this API call
ERRORCODE=10002

It seems like I remember this having to do with Paypal PaymentsPro not being enabled.  I've tried creating multiple business accounts and removing and re-instantiating my credentials.  Nothing seems to work and I can't find anywhere to enable it in the https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/ site.  THe credit card is the fake generated card from a sandbox personal user, but I also tried it with the credit card of the business account and it made no difference.

Can anyone give me some clues?  This is frustrating beyond belief.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <SOAP-ENV:Envelope
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
        xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema"
        SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
        <SOAP-ENV:Header>
            <RequesterCredentials xmlns="urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI" SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1">
                <Credentials xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
                    <Username>business user from paypal sandbox</Username>
                    <Password>password from classic text api credentials</Password>
            <Signature>api from new paypal sandbox business user</Signature>
                    <Subject>email of new paypal sandbox business user</Subject>
                </Credentials>
            </RequesterCredentials>
        </SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <SOAP-ENV:Body>
            <DoDirectPaymentReq xmlns="urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI">
                <DoDirectPaymentRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI">
                <Version xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">1.0</Version>
                <DoDirectPaymentRequestDetails xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
        <PaymentAction>Sale</PaymentAction>
        <PaymentDetails>
            <OrderTotal currencyID="USD">50.00</OrderTotal>
            <ItemTotal currencyID="USD">50.00</ItemTotal>
            <ShippingTotal currencyID="USD">0.00</ShippingTotal>
            <HandlingTotal currencyID="USD">0.00</HandlingTotal>
            <TaxTotal currencyID="USD">0.00</TaxTotal>
            <OrderDescription>LOCAL - </OrderDescription>
            <Custom>LOCAL - </Custom>
            <InvoiceID>LOCAL - 1417</InvoiceID>
            <PaymentItem>
              <Name>Donation</Name>
              <Number>28</Number>
              <Quantity>1</Quantity>
              <SalesTax currencyID="USD">0</SalesTax>
              <Amount currencyID="USD">50.00</Amount>
            </PaymentItem>      </PaymentDetails>
        <CreditCard>
          <CreditCardType>Visa</CreditCardType>
          <CreditCardNumber>4892645783103844</CreditCardNumber>
          <ExpMonth>4</ExpMonth>
          <ExpYear>2018</ExpYear>
          <CardOwner>
            <Payer>john_test@testuser.org</Payer>
            <PayerID></PayerID>
            <PayerStatus>1</PayerStatus>
            <PayerName>
              <FirstName>Test</FirstName>
              <LastName>User</LastName>
            </PayerName>
            <PayerCountry>US</PayerCountry>
            <PayerBusiness></PayerBusiness>
            <Address><Name>Test User</Name>             
                    <Street1>5555 W 55th St</Street1>
                <Street2></Street2>
                <CityName>Somewhere</CityName>
                <StateOrProvince>IL</StateOrProvince>
                <Country>US</Country>
                <Phone>555-555-5555</Phone>
                <PostalCode>55555</PostalCode>
            </Address>
          </CardOwner>
          <CVV2>123</CVV2>
        </CreditCard>
        <IPAddress>my ip address</IPAddress>
        <MerchantSessionId>z78m9bsliz7b7f7</MerchantSessionId>
                    </DoDirectPaymentRequestDetails>
                </DoDirectPaymentRequest>
            </DoDirectPaymentReq>
        </SOAP-ENV:Body>
    </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the values of "Username" and "Subject" match almost exactly? ( '_api1.' in place of '@' ) ?

If they differ and this is intended, what you may have to do is log into the sandbox account as 'Subject' and grant 3rd party API permissions to the Username.

If they don't differ, try omitting Subject. If that doesn't change the response, can you please post the values?

Comment: Yes they do, and when I tried that (even before your suggestion) it gave me the error `You are logging into the account of the API caller of this transaction. Please change your login information and try again.` 

After playing around with the configuration, like removing the subject, I can get it to give me a different error which is `This transaction cannot be processed due to an invalid merchant configuration.`  

Lots of reading / searching implies that this is a Paypal bug with their payments pro not being enabled properly.  I couldn't find anywhere to enable it.

Comment: Invalid Merchant Configuration usually means Pro is not enabled, yes.  Try creating a new Business account in the sandbox and testing with that one's USER/PWD/SIGNATURE

Comment: Yes, I tried that as well to no avail.  Ultimately, I had to contact them to have them enable it for me.  So lame.

Answer (score -1):

HERE IS A LINK MAY IT HELP YOU TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE

http://help.tictail.com/customer/portal/articles/1063813-paypal-error-%22you-do-not-have-permissions-to-make-this-api-call%22